# Stage Wifi Model

Tags: ros, simulation, wifi, simulator-stage, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

it the stage wifi model [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/stage-cvs/group__model__wifi.html] available in the stageros node ? I always get `Unknown model type wifi in world file`

am i doing something wrong or need i to applay a patch? Or isn't it supported by the ros node.
Stage Version is 4.1.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101221/stage-wifi-model/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, as far as i know stageros node only supports laser and recently camera support was added. Maybe you have to use a patch to use this model.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-11-14**:
hi, thanks for the fast replay. I have serched on google but i do not finde where i can download stage patches, do you know where I can get a list ?